# How to change class after the user has stopped typing?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

So I have this form set-up which looks exactly like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FQlS.png The thing I am trying to do is change the form field's class after the user has stopped typing, as shown below after checking in my database if the username/email already exists. This should be done without reloading the page. How can I do this? Preferably with jQuery's (ajax?)

### register.php

```
<?php
require_once 'connect.inc.php';
require_once 'core.inc.php';
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="middlebox">
            <a href="index.php"><h1 class="logo">codeforum+</h1></a>
            <h3 class="welcometext">Create an account on codeforum+</h3>
            <h6>Please fill out all the provided fields to continue with your registration.</h6>
            <h6 style="font-size:10px;">Note : You can only register once on this forum, so make it count. Any further registrations will be prohibited, because your IP address will be in our database.</h6>
            <hr class="linestyle">
            <form action="" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div id="username_form" class="input-group <?php // IF USERNAME EXISTS ADD CLASS 'has-warning' ELSE ADD 'has-success' ?>">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i></span>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter your username here..." name="username">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group <?php // IF EMAIL EXISTS ADD CLASS 'has-warning' ELSE ADD 'has-success' ?> ">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i></span>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter your email here..." name="email">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group <?php // IF PASSWORD HAS NUMBERS,LETTERS, ETC.. ADD CLASS 'has-warning' ELSE ADD 'has-success' ?> ">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></i></span>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter your password here..." name="password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group <?php // IF THIS MATCHES THE PASSWORD ADD CLASS 'has-warning' ELSE ADD 'has-success' ?> ">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></i></span>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Retype your password here..." name="password_retype">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr class="linestyle">
                <p>Which comparison operator is used to compare variables/values in PHP?</p>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Answer the question here..." name="question">
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">I agree to the <a href="#">rules</a> of this forum.
                    </label>
                </div>
                <p class="rules" style="font-size:10px;">Breaking the rules by any means will result in a permanent ban.</p>
                <input class="btn btn-success fullwidth" type="submit" value="Register">
            </form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['password_retype']) && isset($_POST['question']) && isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password_retype = $_POST['password_retype'];
    $question = $_POST['question'];
    $checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];

    if(!empty($username) && !empty($email) && !empty($password) && !empty($password_retype) && !empty($question) && !empty($checkbox)) {
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
        if($sql_run = mysql_query($sql)) {
            $sql_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($sql_run);
            if($sql_num_rows==1) {
                // if username exists change class of the form

            } else {
                // if username doesnt exist - continue
                $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
                if($sql_run = mysql_query($sql)) {
                    $sql_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($sql_run);
                    if($sql_num_rows==1) {
                        // if email exists change class of the form
                    } else {
                        // if email doesnt exist - continue
                    }
                } else {
                    // if query failed
                }
            }
        } else {
            // if query failed
        }
    } else {
        // if fields are empty
    }
}
?>
            <a href="landingpage.php"><p class="small" style="margin-top:10px;">Already have an account?</p></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

### connect.php

```
<?php
$mysql_error = mysql_error(); // change to 404 when finished

$mysql_database = 'codeforum';
$mysql_host = '127.0.0.1';
$mysql_user = 'root';
$mysql_pass = '';

if(!mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass) || !mysql_select_db($mysql_database)) {
    die($mysql_error);
}
?>
```

Comment: The problem is, I don't know nothing about jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Your question might have been easier to answer if you took more time to reduce it to a manageable scenario, but here you go anyway:

1. you'll need a PHP endpoint that checks for username availability.
2. to prevent that endpoint abuse, you'll need to require a PHP session, and store the number of attempts in the last 20 minutes or so in that. If there are too many attempts for your liking it should error out.
3. you'll need a JS handler for making an AJAX request to above endpoint; it will apply your `className` if the endpoint didn't respond with a error.
4. hook up your JS to fire on "change" and use a helper function to `setTimeout` to do the same on "keyup", so you don't hammer your PHP endpoint every time the user releases a key but rather only after a grace period, of say 100ms.
5. go back and implement informative messages for your error conditions, such as "name exists", and "too many attempts".